# Probability question about guessing computer passwords

Tags: probability

Just doing some preparation for an exam,

A computer system uses passwords that are $6$ characters and each character is one of the $26$ letters (a-z) or $10$ integers (0-9). Uppercase letters are not used.

Let $A$ be the event that a password begins with a vowel (either a, e, i, o or u) and let $B$ denote the event that a password ends with an even number (either 0, 2, 4, 6 or 8). Suppose a hacker selects a password at random. What are the probabilities $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(A \cap B)$ and $P(A \cup B)$ ?

With $P(A)$ the way I've thought about it (though I think it's wrong) is:

Passwords have 6 characters: __ __ __ __ __ __

The total number of passwords is therefore (26 Letters + 10 numbers)$^6$ or $36^6$ by the multiplicative law of probability

36 36 36 36 36 36

But a password which begins with a vowel (5 letters to choose) would be

5 36 36 36 36 36

therefore being $(5*36^5)/36^6 = 5/36$

but that doesn't feel right.. I think what that gives me is the probability of there being at least one vowel, not necessarily being at the start?

Comment: It's perfectly right. The probability that there is at least one vowel (not necessarily at the start) is not as simple as this.

Comment: The counting approach you used is fine. However, it can be done more simply. The probability that the first symbol of the password is simply $5/36$, since there are $36$ possibilities for the first symbol, all equally likely, and only $5$ of them "work." Finding $P(B)$ is also straightforward. Finding $P(A \cap B)$ is harder. There your counting approach will work nicely. So will conditional probability, if you have been introduced to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is indeed the probability that there is one vowel. However, this is the same as the probability that the first character is a vowel. Think of it this way: the event A only depends on the first character: the rest can be ignored. This means that the probability you want is the probability that this character is a vowel, which can occur in 5 out of the 36 possibilties, yielding the 5/36 you have calculated another way.

The tricky thing about this question is the part where the hacker generates passwords *at random*. This implies that the characters in the generated password are all independent, which is why it doesn't matter to your calculation that the event A refers to the first character. It could refer to the fifth character; as worded, your answer would come out the same.

Comment: The claim that "your answer is indeed the probability that there is one vowel" is wrong, regardless of how one interprets it: the probability that there is _at least_ one vowel is $1-\left(\frac{31}{36}\right)^6 \approx 0.5923$, while the probability that there is _exactly_ one vowel is $6\cdot\left(\frac{5}{36}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{31}{36}\right)^5 \approx 0.3946$.  Neither of those equals $\frac{5}{36}$.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen so the probability of there being exactly one vowel is the same as the probability of the first letter being a vowel?

Comment: @Arvin: No, that's exactly what I said is _not_ the case.

Comment: Ilmari is correct, I would have gotten that wrong had it been the question. Like the comment indicates, this is a different probability from that of finding exactly one vowel. **If** I understand correctly now, the probability of finding a vowel in the first location is the same as the probability of finding a vowel in any location, but the location must be fixed, or else you get the probability that there is _exactly_ one vowel in Any location calculated above.